# C# PerformanceCounter Requests/Sec not updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, performancecounter

I am making a program, where I need to get some values out from the performance counter.

So far it's been working fine. But when I tried to get the "Requests/Sec" counter for a specific IIS site, I ain't getting any values, like its not updating, at all.
But if I check in "Performance Monitor" on my windows computer, I can see that the same counter works.

This program has admin rights.

A snippet for my code getting this counter looks like this.

```
 public static int GetRequest()
    {

        var cat = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories().FirstOrDefault(s => s.CategoryName.Contains("ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319"));
        var catinstances = cat.GetInstanceNames().First(s => s.Contains("_lm_w3svc_3_root").ToUpper()));
        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319", "Requests/Sec", catinstances, true);
        return unchecked((int)cpuCounter.NextValue());
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: cpuCounter should be static property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep an instance of that Performance Counter around, instead of reinstantiating it on every call.

The following code will keep the counter around in a static member and re-use that instance on the next call to your method:

```
static PerformanceCounter _requestCounter; // keep instance around
static PerformanceCounter cpuCounter  // property with lazy init
{
   get 
   {
      // initialize if we haven't done so.
      if (_requestCounter == null) {
        var cat = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories().FirstOrDefault(s => s.CategoryName.Contains("ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319"));
        var catinstances = cat.GetInstanceNames().First(s => s.ToUpper().Contains("_WEB"));
        _requestCounter = new PerformanceCounter("ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319", "Requests/Sec", catinstances, true);

      }
      return _requestCounter;
   }
}

public static int GetRequest()
{  
    return unchecked((int)cpuCounter.NextValue());
}
```

Comment: Okay. i tried to change it to static, but didn't do anything. I am still not getting anything from it in my code. but i can see the request in perfmon. so i know it's getting request on that performance counter. this is so weird

Comment: @DaCh you did notice I changed what is in the Contains, right? `_WEB` is an instance on my dev box. Can you otherwise try `TOTAL` just to see if it picks up anything? I don';t expect it to be a permission issiue.

Comment: And did you call it two or more times? Caliing it once won't do much.

Comment: i have not try calling totalt. since i need it for one site. I'm i will test it to se if i get any. And i tried writing it to the console every 500 ms. while i was calling my site over and over.

Comment: Just tried total. and that worked. but again, I need it for specific site

Comment: Can you console.writeline what is in catinstances and see if that matches the site you're interested in.

Comment: It does. is the right site i am checking the values for.

Comment: That is super weird.

Comment: Okay. think i found out what is wrong. I'm am hosting 4 sites, and i want to check this for 2 of them. So i made a loop checking for one, then another. by a string variable containing the site. And this won't do. if i check just for one site, it works. But does this mean i can't do this dynamic?

Comment: Well, you need one performance counter for each site in that case. A single performance counter instance should bind to one site.

Comment: Do you want an aggregate of two counters?

Comment: From 2 differences sites? can i do that?

Comment: Yes, have two performance counters in a static  List<> or so and then sum their NextValues()

Comment: ahh. you mean like that. yha. i could do that. but still. how can i make the performance counter on runtime?

Comment: I can reviisit this tonight, currently I''m not on a suitable dev box

Comment: Hey. I just got it to work. And It was because i need to create each of them. Many thanks for your help. gonna mark this as the answer.